# How to wrap nested span content rendered by mathlive

Tags: javascript, html, css, latex

In my project(angular) I have to get latex inputs and render them. For that purpose I use mathlive. When I render using the `convertLatexToMarkup` function (provided by mathlive) it creates a lot of nested spans and applies style to it. The problem is I am unable to wrap them in a div, for which I have set width, the content just overflows the div.

I tried setting the `white-space:normal` style of span elements as suggested elsewhere, but it didn't work or rather it doesn't cover the entire width of the div. If I set `white-space:nowrap` the content just overflows the div.

A minimal example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/mathlive/dist/mathlive-static.css" />

    <style>
    /*  
        span {
            white-space:normal;
        } */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:200px;background-color: yellow;">
<p id="toberendered">This is a very long text with math content in it \sqrt[3]{x+y}. This is a very long text with math content in it \sqrt[3]{x+y}</p>

</div>

<p id="nottoberendered">Preview \sqrt[3]{x+y}</p>

<script type="module">
import { convertLatexToMarkup,renderMathInDocument } from 'https://unpkg.com/mathlive/dist/mathlive.min.mjs';

function  replaceSpaces(input){
    if(input == null){return "";}
    var output = input.toString().replace(/ /g,"\\; ");
    return "$$" + output + "$$";
  }

var el= document.getElementById("toberendered");
el.innerHTML = convertLatexToMarkup(replaceSpaces(el.innerText),{
 mathstyle:  'textstyle', 
 letterShapeStyle:  'upright' });   
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I wrap the content to fit the width of a div?

Comment: Do I correctly understand: You want to wrap `$$This is a very long text with math content in it \sqrt[3]{x+y}.$$`? LaTeX wouldn't wrap it. The text overflows the page size.

Comment: yes, `$$This is a very long text with math content in it \sqrt[3]{x+y}.$$` (with spaces replaced with \;) should be wrapped in that yellow div.

Comment: IMHO it shouldn't be wrapped using HTML, CSS or JavaScript. You're rendering LaTeX and this line isn't wrapped in LaTeX. If you want to wrap it you should wrap it in a LaTeX way otherwise you're not actually rendering LaTeX.

Comment: Currently you are setting the whole line as math formula. Usually you would only set the mathematical expressions, like: `This is a very long text with math content in it $$\sqrt[3]{x+y}$$.`. You're using LaTeX in an unintended way and are trying to fix problems that wouldn't occur if you use it in an intended way. It's impossible to detect which parts should be set as math. `A` could be an English word or mathematical variable. If the users know how to type `\sqrt[3]{x+y}` they should also know how to type `$$\sqrt[3]{x+y}$$`.

Comment: @jabaa Thanks, I did as you have suggested. Now the users enter latex code with \\[ symbol and \\] symbol. Turned out simpler than expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is wrapped correctly when you just declare the actual math parts of the text as such and render these individually:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/mathlive/dist/mathlive-static.css" />

    <style>
    /*  
        span {
            white-space:normal;
        } */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:200px;background-color: yellow;">
<p>This is a very long text with math content in it $$\sqrt[3]{x+y}$$. This is a very long text with math content in it $$\sqrt[3]{x+y}$$</p>
</div>

    <script type="module">
        import { renderMathInDocument } from 'https://unpkg.com/mathlive/dist/mathlive.min.mjs';
        renderMathInDocument();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it won't work for my case. SInce
1) the content inside the p tag will be a preview of user entered text and the $$ rule cannot be enforced. Although I would try to use regex function
2) there will be other text whose content should not be rendered (hence the toberendered id). `renderMathInDocument()` renders everything

I will update my example to include text that should not be rendered too

Comment: Ok, I didn't see that from the example. But the core claim may also be valid for that situation: You wouldn't create a latex math environment with so much text - Latex won't break it. Instead, maybe using `<span>` only for the formulas and render only these with `convertLatexToMarkup` may do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I combined your idea with @jabaa idea. I made the user enter latex code with \\[ symbol and \\] symbol. And I replaced the brackets with span and rendered them alone

Answer (score 0):

I needed an example of how to work with MathLive this way. Thank you for your hard work. Fixing the stylesheet was rather simple.

These are the styles I used to achieve the effect you want:

```css
      .ML__latex {
        display: block;
        white-space: normal;
      }

      .ML__base, .ML__latex {
        width: auto;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/mathlive/dist/mathlive-static.css" />

    <style>
  .ML__latex {
    display: block;
    white-space: normal;
  }
  .ML__base, .ML__latex {
    width: auto;
  }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:200px;background-color: yellow;">
<p id="toberendered">This is a very long text with math content in it \sqrt[3]{x+y}. This is a very long text with math content in it \sqrt[3]{x+y}</p>

</div>

<p id="nottoberendered">Preview \sqrt[3]{x+y}</p>

<script type="module">
import { convertLatexToMarkup,renderMathInDocument } from 'https://unpkg.com/mathlive/dist/mathlive.min.mjs';

function  replaceSpaces(input){
    if(input == null){return "";}
    var output = input.toString().replace(/ /g,"\\; ");
    return "$$" + output + "$$";
  }

var el= document.getElementById("toberendered");
el.innerHTML = convertLatexToMarkup(replaceSpaces(el.innerText),{
 mathstyle:  'textstyle', 
 letterShapeStyle:  'upright' });   
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

BTW, I made a [code pen](https://codepen.io/mslinn/pen/BabJWgW) with improved JavaScript